# Deleting all logs based on a specific application name in Graylog

Tags: graylog2

“I want to delete all logs from the application_name:PMA.WS.OPCService.exe received in the last month in Graylog. I would appreciate your assistance in this matter.Since I did not delete the messages, the logos do not appear.  Have a good day.